# JDBC-ResultSet is closed in while-Loop

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset, h2

I'm having a really bad time with a ResultSet, which is closed within a while-Loop for iterating this ResultSet. I have know the exact line in which the ResultSet is closed, but i have no idea why.

```
    public LinkedList<Athlet> alleAbrufen () throws SQLException {
        LinkedList<Athlet> alleAthleten = new LinkedList<Athlet>();
        String abrufenAthleten = "SELECT * FROM Athlet ORDER BY athlet_id";
        ResultSet athleten_rs = stmt.executeQuery(abrufenAthleten);
        while (athleten_rs.next()) {
            long id = athleten_rs.getInt(1);
            String name = athleten_rs.getString(2);
            LinkedList<Leistung> alleLeistungen = alleAbrufen((int) (id)); //after this line the ResultSet gets closed
            alleAthleten.add(new Athlet(id, name, alleLeistungen));
        }
        return alleAthleten;
    }

    public LinkedList<Leistung> alleAbrufen(int athlet_id) throws SQLException {
        LinkedList<Leistung> alleLeistungen = new LinkedList<Leistung>();
        String selectLeistungen = "SELECT * FROM Leistung WHERE athlet_id="+athlet_id;
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectLeistungen);
        while (rs.next()) {
            long id = rs.getInt(1); 
            String bezeichnung = rs.getString(2);
            String datum = rs.getString(3);
            double geschwindigkeit = rs.getDouble(4);
            boolean selectedForSlopeFaktor = rs.getBoolean(5);
            int strecke_id = rs.getInt(7);
            long longAthlet_id = (long) athlet_id;
            Leistung leistung = new Leistung(strecke_id, longAthlet_id, bezeichnung, datum, geschwindigkeit);
            leistung.setLeistungID(id);
            leistung.setIsUsedForSlopeFaktor(selectedForSlopeFaktor);
            alleLeistungen.add(leistung);
        }
        return alleLeistungen;
    }
```

I marked the line after which the `ResultSet` is closed with a comment. `Alle` other methods, constructors, etc used in the above example are tested an working properly. Does anyone have a clue why calling the second method closes the `ResultSet` in the first method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Statement` can only maintain a single group of `ResultSet`s per executed statement. Since you share the same `Statement stmt` for your two methods, in `alleAbrufen` the `Statement` executes another statement, which will break the reference to the prior `ResultSet`.

The best solution for this case is to create a `Statement` per statement execution. This is, every method should contain its unique `Statement` and related `ResultSet`s.

```
public LinkedList<Athlet> alleAbrufen () throws SQLException {
    LinkedList<Athlet> alleAthleten = new LinkedList<Athlet>();
    String abrufenAthleten = "SELECT * FROM Athlet ORDER BY athlet_id";
    //here
    Statement stmtAlleAbrufen = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet athleten_rs = stmtAlleAbrufen.executeQuery(abrufenAthleten);
    while (athleten_rs.next()) {
        long id = athleten_rs.getInt(1);
        String name = athleten_rs.getString(2);
        LinkedList<Leistung> alleLeistungen = alleAbrufen((int) (id)); //after this line the ResultSet gets closed
        alleAthleten.add(new Athlet(id, name, alleLeistungen));
    }
    return alleAthleten;
}

public LinkedList<Leistung> alleAbrufen(int athlet_id) throws SQLException {
    LinkedList<Leistung> alleLeistungen = new LinkedList<Leistung>();
    //here again, but since you need to use parameters in your query
    //use PreparedStatement instead
    //note that I commented the current query
    //String selectLeistungen = "SELECT * FROM Leistung WHERE athlet_id="+athlet_id;
    //this is how a query with parameters look like
    String selectLeistungen = "SELECT * FROM Leistung WHERE athlet_id=?";
    //the connection prepares the statement
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(selectLeistungen);
    //then we pass the parameters
    pstmt.setInt(1, athlet_id);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        long id = rs.getInt(1); 
        String bezeichnung = rs.getString(2);
        String datum = rs.getString(3);
        double geschwindigkeit = rs.getDouble(4);
        boolean selectedForSlopeFaktor = rs.getBoolean(5);
        int strecke_id = rs.getInt(7);
        long longAthlet_id = (long) athlet_id;
        Leistung leistung = new Leistung(strecke_id, longAthlet_id, bezeichnung, datum, geschwindigkeit);
        leistung.setLeistungID(id);
        leistung.setIsUsedForSlopeFaktor(selectedForSlopeFaktor);
        alleLeistungen.add(leistung);
    }
    return alleLeistungen;
}
```

Don't forget to close the resources, `Statement` and `ResultSet`, after using them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It worked for me. Some kind of silly mistake to use the same ResultSet twice...anyway, Thanks, Luiggi!

Comment: @Shikari you were using the same Statement object twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem's answer comes from the javadoc:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `Statement` a class variable and you are  using the same for both the queries? Is yes, it's wrong. You can have only one `ResultSet` per `Statement`.

See the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).